# some commands not wroking on remote servers through ssh (shell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have to run some userdefined commands on remote servers. So I do the following. It works for many commands such as `crontab -l`, `ls`, `date +%s`, etc... However, it doesn't work for `ip addr`

When I actually ssh INSIDE those server `ip addr` works fine. But when I execute it using ssh it doesnt.

This is how I execute it.

```
$ sshpass -p myPassword ssh -q root@127.0.0.1 'ip addr' > $PWD/tmp
$ cat $PWD/tmp
```

Again, this works for any commands I've tried so far except `ip addr`.
For `ip addr` it gives the following output

```
bash: ip: command not found
```

So i was wondering why and if there's anything wrong I'm doing....

Also, please don't sugges to use `rsync` or any other nondefault linux command since the environment I work in does not have them nor do I have the permission to install.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is caused because a non-interactive ssh session does not source your login profile, which amongst other things is setting your `PATH` variable.

The default path does not contain `/sbin`, which is the usual location of the `ip` command.

Comment: I see... So you're telling me that when I run commands through ssh, it kinds of has "limited" access? Also, Is there any way to fix this? Or it really depends on the command I want to run through ssh.

Comment: It's not that it has limited access, it's that because you're running non-interactively you may need to do some work yourself. In the case of the problem with the ip command, you could make the command invocation `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH ip addr` which should solve the problem in that case. Doing more than one command over ssh may be better accomplished by copying it remotely using scp, and then invoking it over ssh. That way you can add a line setting the PATH to the script, and thus only perform it the once.

Comment: Ok i see. Because I don't know what the user would want to execute, can i just put `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH` before every command? Let's say the user command is stored in `$myCommand`. I'll simply do `sshpass -p mypass ssh root@127.0.0.1 'PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH $myCommand'`

Comment: and also putting `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH` for **ALL** commands won't affect anything else?

Comment: Unless you've got extra variants of your commands in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`, the worst effect would be the extra search time for the commands.